# visual force component in salesforce

Tags: visualforce-component, vf-email-template

Visual Force Component:

```
<apex:component controller="myController1" access="global"> 
<p /> 
<apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1" >{!url}/{!$User.Id}?isUserEntityOverride=1&amp;noredirect=1</apex:outputLink> <br /> 

<apex:outputLabel value="{!userName}" id="someId" /> 
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userPhone}" id="someId2" /> 

</apex:component>
```

Visual Force Template code:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="SOA - User {!$User.Username}" recipientType="user"  relatedToType="order">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
        <body>
        <br>Hi,</br>
        <br></br>

             <br>User <c:ant/>  does not have JDE ALIAS Assigned.

             Click on below link to go to this user setup:
            <apex:outputLink value="<c:ant/>/{!$User.Id}"><c:URL /></apex:outputlink>



             </body>

            </html>
            </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
          </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**In Vf Template first `<c:ant/>` should display only username and `<c:ant/>`should display only link how to access the Visual force component to Visual Force Template code how? Please Guide me for the Answer**

**How to access the username only from vf component to vf template?**

Comment: can you please rephrase question?

Comment: @ArturKępczyński the component contains both the username and salesforce instance link,in vf  template email i have to use username in one place and link in another place,if i used <c:ant/>  this command it displays both the username and mail in one place

Comment: @ArturKępczyński  in Vf template code user <c:ant/> it display the username only there from Vf component and <apex:outputlink value =
"<c:ant/> it would display the link only salesforce link only here

Comment: @ArturKępczyński if you want controller please see the link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148889/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-the-apex-class-controller-to-visual-force-component

Comment: How to call user name seperately like <c:ant/>.username and <c:ant/>.link in Vf template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you use parameters to customize a component. That might look like this:

```
<apex:component controller="myController1" access="global"> 
    <apex:attribute name="showUrl" assignTo="{!showUserUrl}" type="Boolean" description="Show the user url" />
    <apex:attribute name="showName" assignTo="{!showUserName}" type="Boolean" description="Show the user name" />

<apex:outputText rendered="{!showUserUrl}">
    <apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1" >
        {!url}/{!$User.Id}?isUserEntityOverride=1&amp;noredirect=1</apex:outputLink> <br /> 
</apex:outputText>

<apex:outputText rendered="{!showUserName}">
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userName}" id="someId" /> 
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userPhone}" id="someId2" /> 
</apex:outputText>

</apex:component>
```

You'd also want to add the relevant Boolean variables to your controller:

```
public class myController1 {
    public Boolean showUserUrl { get; set; }
    public Boolean showUserName { get; set; }
    // The rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: when i am using the value in subject in vf template it is showing Error:Error: AutoEmailsent line 1, column 47: The value of attribute "subject" associated with an element type "messaging:emailTemplate" must not contain the '<' character 
Error Error: The value of attribute "subject" associated with an element type "messaging:emailTemplate" must not contain the '<' character.  I am using subject as  <c:ant showName="true" /> @sfdcfox How to rectify the error

Comment: can you please see the link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149083/how-do-i-put-dynamic-context-in-the-subject-attribute-of-an-email-template @sfdcfox

Comment: it is not possible ah @sfdcfox